# Sharepoint not updating user's new last name after it has been changed in AD

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

We are currently on SharePoint 2016 on-prem. There is a user whose last name changed but sharepoint is still showing her maiden name. I see her "old" last name in the user information list but don't see her new last name. Too, when a user's name is updated, changed etc it's done in AD but not sure how to update it on the sharepoint side of things. Help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have AD Import or MIM set up to synchronize from Active Directory to the User Profile Service Application? Also, when you say 'user's name', do you mean the `sAMAccountName` attribute, as that would require `Move-SPUser` or `stsadm -o migrateuser` rather than letting the standard UPSA sync process take care of `givenName` or `surName` attributes.

Comment: I'm new to this so I do apologize for the miswording... So the user who's name changed would be their last name (and first) that displays in the top right hand corner of sharepoint when they go onto the sharepoint site. It displays their old last name still as it didn't update the new last name.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Please remember to accept the helpful answer if you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just one specific account and basic properties like *display name* and *email* you can force this account to sync from AD (in case you have standard NTLM\Kerberos authentication scheme):
`Set-SPUser "i:0#.w|domain\login" -Web "http://your-sharepoint-root-site" -SyncFromAD`

Or even for all SharePoint users:
`$web = Get-SPWeb "http://your-sharepoint-root-site";`
`Get-SPUser -Limit ALL -Web $web | Set-SPUser -Web $web -SyncFromAD -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Answer (score 0):

1.If it is just a certain property, please go to User Profile Service application -> Manage User Properties -> Check if the property marked as replicable. Only properties that are marked as "Replicable" are synced.

2.If all profile properties are failing to sync for a given site collection

(1)Make sure the site you are focused on is set to synch by running following PowerShell.

```
$URL = https://yourSiteCollectionHere #The site collection you want to force Full sync on

get-spsite -id $URL | % {[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSynch]::ScheduleSiteForFullSynchronization($_); $_.Close() }
```

(2)Then run the “ - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization” timer job by doing a "run now" on the job in central administration or by running following PowerShell.

```
$tj = get-sptimerjob | ? {$_.name -like "_ProfSync"}

Start-SPTimerJob $tj
```

Comment: You'll need to change the get to the following:
`get-sptimerjob | ? {$_.name -like "*_ProfSync*"}`